# parallelogram shape in css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make a header menu background with the help of parallelogram shape in css.
Problem is my header menu text is also show in parallelogram style . I want my text style as a straight/normal.

Here is my css code:-

```
.nav-bg{
   background-color:rgba(2,2,2,0.9);
   float:left;
    Skew 
   -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg); 
   -moz-transform: skew(-60deg); 
   -o-transform: skew(-60deg);
   transform: skew(-60deg);
}
<div class="nav-bg">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav"><li>test</li></ul>
</div>
```

Kindly advise me any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{
    margin: 30px 150px;
}

.nav-bg {    
    width: 150px;/*for example*/
    height: 150px;/*for example*/
    background-color:rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-60deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-60deg);
            transform: skew(-60deg);    
}
.nav-bg ul{
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: skew(60deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(60deg);
         -o-transform: skew(60deg);
            transform: skew(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bg">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```